# Need to return default function only when all "if" statements are not true

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, if-statement, return

So I have two functions **feedback** and **noResult**

```
feedback() {
      const feedData = this.$store.state.feedback.feedbackData2;

      return feedData.filter((feedback) => {
        // Custom Date Filter
        if (
          new Date(feedback.date) >= new Date(this.filteredOptions[0]) &&
          new Date(feedback.date) <= new Date(this.filteredOptions[1])
        ) {
          return true;
        }

        // 7 days filter
        if (
          new Date(feedback.date) >=
            new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7)) &&
          new Date(feedback.date) <= new Date() &&
          this.filteredOptions == "7 days"
        ) {
          return true;
        }
        // 15 days filter
        if (
          new Date(feedback.date) >=
            new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 15)) &&
          new Date(feedback.date) <= new Date() &&
          this.filteredOptions == "15 days"
        ) {
          return true;
        }
        // 1 month filter
        if (
          new Date(feedback.date) >=
            new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1)) &&
          new Date(feedback.date) <= new Date() &&
          this.filteredOptions == "1 month"
        ) {
          return true;
        }
        // 6 months filter
        if (
          new Date(feedback.date) >=
            new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 6)) &&
          new Date(feedback.date) <= new Date() &&
          this.filteredOptions == "6 months"
        ) {
          return true;
        }
        // 1 year filter
        if (
          new Date(feedback.date) >=
            new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1)) &&
          new Date(feedback.date) <= new Date() &&
          this.filteredOptions == "1 year"
        ) {
          return true;
        }
        // Star Rating Filter
        if (feedback.star === this.filteredOptions) {
          return true;
        }
        // Filter for All
        if (feedback.all === "all" && this.filteredOptions == "All") {
          return true;
        }
          return this.noResult()
      });
    },
```

```
 noResult() {
      this.dialog = true;
    },
```

**feedData** is basically an array of objects with similar keys but different values. For example:

```
  feedbackData2: [
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "Joshua Fransix",
      image: "landingImage.png",
      email: "test256@gmail.com",
      phoneNumber: "09012276905",
      date: "07/31/2022",
      message: "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit eos impedit consequuntur ipsam",
      star: 3,
      all: "all",
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "David Beckham",
      image: "landingImage.png",
      email: "good@ymail.com",
      phoneNumber: "08011123411",
      date: "01/01/2022",
      message: "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit eos impedit consequuntur ipsam      aspernatur quasi quae, possimus harum autem animi. Sit eos impedit consequuntur ipsam     aspernatur quasi quae, possimus harum autem animi. Sit eos impedit consequuntur ipsam     aspernatur quasi quae, possimus harum autem animi. Sit eos impedit consequuntur ipsam     aspernatur quasi quae, possimus harum autem animi.",
      star: 5,
      all: "all"
    },
]
```

I want **noResult** to be returned only when all of the **if statements** in **feedback** are not **true**. But for some reason even when they are true, **noResult** is still returned.

Comment: "But for some reason even when they are true, noResult is still returned" - there's no such reason. Proceed from the fact that your observations are wrong. You could set up a breakpoint and see yourself on what conditions this line is reached

Comment: Instead of `Array.filter()` method you can use `Array.every()` and then based on the boolean value you can perform the action.